# Unable to find API Key for my blog

Tags: api

I have the blog http://kracekumar.wordpress.com, I need to find the API KEY of my blog,I clicked on Global Dashboard->My profile,it was mentioned in wordpress site that it will be found in top left side,but I can't find it.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "help" on wp.com?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the API key by logging into [WordPress.com](http://wordpress.com/), clicking "My Account" on the top bar, and clicking the "API Key" link.

Comment: After getting to that page i can't find the api key any where.

Comment: Depending on your account you may then see "You can get your API key direct from Akismet now." with a link to http://akismet.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wordpress.com/api-keys/

> "If you already have a WordPress.com
>   account, your API key is listed on
>   your profile page, which you can get
>   to by clicking the “My Account” link
>   in the top left when you’re logged
>   in."

Comment: You may also be able to find it at:  http://akismet.com/personal/